# With appium which language will be compatible when application is built on dot net?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, ios, languages

My application is built on dot net and I want to automate the application using Appium tool.
I am not able to decide which language should I use with Appium to automate this app. Considering this is a mobile app and I want to test in android, iOS and on the web too.

Answer (score 2):

**Straight forward Answer:** As Appium is a cross-language tool for mobile automation & it's independent of product language developed. you can use any language listed below.

- Ruby
- Python
- Java
- JavaScript
- PHP
- C#

> I am not able to decide which language should I use with Appium to
>   automate this app.

**But the answer to this question is not straight forward:** Some factors have to be considered before start working.

- The current language being used by the company for development: If an organization has everyone using C#(Assuming you are using C#), then that should be the ideal language to use.
- Introducing a new language isn’t easy better to use a language that QA testers are already comfortable with.
- Developer support for the programming language should also be considered. suppose if local developers are experienced with a particular language, then that language is a better choice for QA teams as well. In case testers require help with the language, defects, or development tools, it becomes easier to make use of the already available in-house expertise.
- For individuals who haven’t programmed before, using script-friendly languages like Python, Ruby etc. could be the best way to go.
- Java is the most commonly used language, but my personal opinion is that scripts can be complex because of the relatively complicated syntax.

Comment: Consider an example. It is complex to automate ms dynamics application using java.But is it is less complex using C# protractor. Because MS dynamics is build using c#,  dot net. Like wise it should not create any issue if I choose java.However I am comfortable using java.

Comment: As I said, you can use any client language to automate.